# Why is 0 sometimes green and sometimes red in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, rounding, precision, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet in which I have a column with totals. If it's zero or less, it should be green. If it's more than zero it should be red. But when it's zero, it's still red sometimes. Why?

PS: The values are the result of a SUMIF function.

[image: The conditions]

Comment: Is the value *really* 0, or is it a very small fraction that displays as 0?

Comment: It SHOULD be 0. But I took a look and if you add decimals, after like 10 0s there's suddenly some other number. Is it because of float problems in Javascript? I's think Google should have fixed it?

Comment: Nevermind, I found another issue online. Even Google didn't fix the floating number precision... :/ it sucks though...

Comment: @OlivierVanBulck Maybe you can add a rounding function to your cells?

Comment: Yep, did that now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the problem here is the precision in web browsers of floating point numbers. The fix for me was to add the ROUND() function around the SUMIF().

Comment: The same happens on desktop apps